carpeta .git corrupta. la tuve que borrar
tuve un problema con la carpeta (.git), la tuve que borrar.  pense que al hacer clon de lo que ya tenia en github recuperia esos commit por lo menos, pero al hacer el clon y ver los commit no tengo ninguno, tenia entendido que este clon incorpora todo. incluso viene con la carpeta .git incluida, pero no me aparecen los commit, que ya tengo en github. ¿que estoy haciendo mal? puedo recuperar esos commit ?. de ante mano muchas gracias.

No hay mucho que puedas hacer si no tienes una copia de lo que se perdió. Puede que aún quede una copia en disco, pero puede ser o bien inusable o esa versión que eliminaste, la cual ya estaba corrupta.

Si has clonado un repositorio desde GitHub y no ves los commits que esperabas, puede ser que hayas clonado una rama equivocada.
Verifica que la ruta de tu reporitorio sea el correcto.
Verifica en qué rama te encuentras y si es la rama donde esperabas ver tus commits.
git branch
git branch -r

Si no estás en la rama correcta, cambia de rama usando
git checkout nombre-de-la-rama

Una ves estando dentro de la rama puedes ver el historial de commits usando:
git log

Para poder recuperar Commits Perdidos puedes realizar lo siguiente:
Verifica el origen del repositorio:
git remote -v

Obtén toda la información del repositorio remoto:
git fetch --all

Restablece la rama local para que coincida con la remota:
git reset --hard origin/nombre-de-la-rama

Esto debería asegurarse de que tu rama local coincida exactamente con la rama remota.

muchas gracias fragoso, ya entendi lo que estaba pasando,. estaba inicializando la carpeta que cree para el clon, entonces estaba creando el (.git) que no tenia nada y el clon que traia el el otro .git venia dentro de otra carpeta, por lo que se creaba otra ruta para este . algo simple entre commillas, pero ya lo solucione, pero tus consejos me ayudaron. gracias
